# what does __init_refok keyword means in linux kernel code?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, keyword, embedded-linux, c-preprocessor

While browsing the kernel code, I came accross a keyword that is used in several kernel init functions, `__init_refok`.

some of the lines I came accross are like

```
void __init_refok free_initmem(void)
static void __init_refok vgacon_scrollback_startup(void)
const struct linux_logo * __init_refok fb_find_logo(int depth)
void noinline __init_refok rest_init(void)
```

and others.

I searched for the reference , from that I came to know that it is defined as a preprocessor macro in `include/linux/init.h`, line 71.

After browsing that, I got the following codes

```
#define __init_refok     __ref
```

and

```
#define __ref            __section(.ref.text) noinline
```

After that, I am losing track.

If anyone can let me know what is the purpose of using that keyword in the code, it will be very helpful.

[I am looking for the basic functionality achieved by using this keyword, just like using `__init`  helps to put the initialization code in seperate memory location to be cleared after init process has been completed.]

Thanks in advance.

### EDIT

In the `include/linux/init.h`, it is mentioned like `__init_refok` is to supress the warning from modpost check, due to any reference form normal code to init section code, but still, I am not getting it exactly. Does that mean that these codes will ba place somewhere else? How actually the behaviour differs from the normal behaviour by using `__init_refok` keyword?

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, [include/linux/init.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/init.h?v=2.6.38#L71) clearly documents the purpose of `__init_refok`. As you have mentioned

> using __init helps to put the initialization code in separate memory
>   location to be cleared after init process has been completed.

compiler generates a warning when we use the data or code from the `separate memory` as they might will be removed at the time of the execution of the particular code referencing them.

`__init_refok` is a way to tell the compiler that you are aware and consciously referencing the initialization code or data. It means **ref** erencing **init** section is **ok** for you. Thus compiler does not generate any warning.

The file also documents that, though the warning is suppressed, it is the programmer's responsibility write such code that refers init section data or code.

> of course, no warning does not mean code is correct, so optimally
>   document why the __ref is needed and why it's OK

In your example, the functions `free_initmem(void)` is probably referring to some data or code, that are tagged with `_init`.

The `_init_refok` tag does not remove the code neither relocate. The code is treated as ordinary except, if it contains any reference to init code or data, warning will be suppressed.

Comment: Dear @Dipto, I noticed that if we need to have a piece of code that will be cleared when the kernel initialization will be over, then we use the __init keyword. otherwise, the code will not be removed. In the example function mentioned above, only __init_refok has been used, no __init keyword is there, so these codes are not going to be cleared after initialization. If we refer the code from non-init section, that should be OK. So, does that imply that __init_refok is being used just to supress the modpost warning or something else also is performed by using __init_ref keyword?

Comment: Function tagged with `_init_refok` will not be removed as these are not init code. these functions are may be using some code or data that are tagged with `_init`, which will be removed after execution. so referring to them will produce run time error, and that's why modpost throws a warning. But if the init code is still valid (due to any reason), those code or data can still be accessed. So, if you know that the init code or data will be valid during the access, you don't want the warning then.